# Flutter#4 : How can i achieve this in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a screen showing connected device info and when i click on it it shows details. i have _connectDevice function to record device's data and convert it to device_information. however at this screen i don't know how to call the data from the scan_device that i created earlier. Can someone help me?

> 

```
 Future<void> connectDevice(Data data) async {
        var connectRequest = {
          'serialNumber': data.serialNumber,
          'modelName': data.modelName,
          'ipAddr': data.ipAddr,
        };
        print("----");
        print(connectRequest);
        var apiEndpoint = VNPTTechAPI.shared;
        await apiEndpoint.connectDevice(connectRequest);
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'deviceInformation');
      }
```

> 

```
return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => _connectDevice(listDevice[index]),
                    child: Card(
                      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(12),
                        ),
                      ),
```

> 

You can see more of my code here : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PoKzQpOjw6Z8NTTu4qJNOpy2bu7OBgolwoc1dXwvP-s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: what i need now is to be able to get _listdevice and point to each element like modelM or ipAddr at device_information screen

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `listDevice` data to `/deviceInformation`  route through `arguments`. Something like this in `connectDevice` function:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/deviceInformation', arguments: listDevice);
```

And then access them in `build` method of a widget in on `/deviceInformation'

```
final arguments = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Data;
```

For more information on this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushNamed.html

Comment: i have tried and always get an error which is "_CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Data' in type cast)"

Comment: Could you remove cast and print arguments and see if it contains the data?


final arguments = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
print(arguments);

Comment: my code as soon as I click on the card to switch to device_information immediately gives an error and points back to "final arguments = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments; ". I can't print out arguments.

Comment: i just tried again and "arguments" prints out "null"

Comment: So check listDevice data before you pass it so that you're sure that you're not passing null. Print listDevice before navigating and see which value it has

Comment: listDevice's data is still there before I pass it to device_information. I printed listDivice before using Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'deviceInformation', arguments: listDevice);